# Update JSON value with ijson in Python

Tags: python, json, ijson

I am working on a very big JSON file, and I decided to use the ijson library.

Now I want to update some value in this JSON file, but I don't know how.

For example, from:

```
{"age": 25, "gender": "M"}
```

update to:

```
{"age": 30, "gender": "F"}
```

by using the ijson library.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the examples in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/.  For editing you can simply use the json library. First load/deserialize the json object then edit and finally use the dump method to update your json file.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I already thought this, but the problem is that if the file is very large (Gbs), only load the file by using json library requires a lot of time. Is there a way to address this issue?

Comment: You can use pandas dataframes or graphlab SFrame to load large json files. Also both the libraries are more stable than ijson streaming.